# XML Deserialization on windows phone

Tags: c#

I am attempting to deserialize an XML file on windows phone according to [Handling XML files on Windows Phone](http://diggthedrazen.com/2011/07/05/xml-deserialization-on-windows-phone/)

The XML file looks similar to this

```
<positions>  
<POS LAT=12312312 LON=23113123\>
</positions>
```

In C# I am using,

```
[XMLRoot("positions")]
public class Positions    
{
[XmlArray] //These two lines seem to be where the problem is...
[XmlArrayItem("POS")]
public ObservableCollection<POS> Collection {get;set;}
}
```

class POS.cs looks like

```
public class POS.cs
{
[XMLAttribute("LAT")]
public string LAT{get;set;}
```

What should [XmlArray("FOO")] and [XmlArrayItem("BAR")] look like?
something is not working correctly here... 
Thanks for the help before hand!

Answer (score 1):

XmlArray/XmlArrayItem are for where you want a two-tier hierarchy; in your case, the `POS` are direct children of `positions`, so `XmlElement` is the correct layout:

```
[XmlRoot("positions")]
public class Positions    
{
    [XmlElement("POS")]
    public ObservableCollection<POS> Collection {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: +1, just fix `[XMLRoot("positions")]` which should be `[XmlRoot("positions")]` and `[Element("POS")]` which should be `[XmlElement("POS")]`.

Comment: @Darin fair enough; the first was copy/paste from the question; the second was my own carelessness